# While loop in shell script computes too many times

Tags: shell, ubuntu

I am running a simple shell script to execute a tcl file in Ubuntu. I have previously used FOR Loops for my scripts but this time it was more suitable to use the while loop. However, my while loop runs more iterations than the number I specified, i.e the code is:

```
a=1

while [ $a -lt 5 ]

do   
    ns loopTest.tcl >> outputTest.txt
    a=$(( a+1 ))

done
```

I am running 5 iterations (this is just a test, I actually need it to run a 100 times) but I am getting the output 12 times. I have changed the number of iterations but I still get more than the iterations. I am really puzzled as to why this is happening.

I'll greatly appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Do you get the output exactly once when you remove the while loop?

Comment: Your loop only runs 4 times (when `a` is 1, 2, 3, and 4, *not* when `a` is 5). Also, `outputTest.txt` would accumulate values between runs, since you are always appending to it.

Comment: echo a inside the loop

Comment: Thank you @Thomas, I don't know why I didn't check that. It was just a silly oversight on my part, the tcl file itself gives me 3 outputs when I run it once so that is why I was getting 12 when I run it 4 times. *face-palm*

Comment: @Ndilo Happens to the best of us. I summarized everything in a proper answer for the benefit of others who might run into a similar problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

As @chepner points out, your loop runs 4 times, not 5. This is because you start with `a = 1` and you only loop as long as `a` is less than 5, i.e., through the values 1, 2, 3, 4.

Since you see your output being printed 12 times, it looks like your tcl code inside the loop actually prints the output 3 times each time it is invoked.